# python threading Event : why do we need clear()

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-multithreading

I am quite new to Python. I am trying my hands on `threading` module. I came across `Event` objects.
Event objects has
`wait`
 `set`
 `clear`
functions. I understand what wait, set and clear are doing. But I do not quite understand why is there a separate clear method. Could that not be included in set method implementation?
 Most of the code I have seen till now has `set` method followed by a `clear` method. So that the subsequent wait method calls wait.
 I come from Java world and I couldn't help but to compare this with wait and notify method calls. There is no equivalent method call in Java for clear.

Is there any use case where one would use set but not clear method?

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#threading.Event

Comment: @404pio I have read this. This doesn't answer my question "Is there any use case where one would use set but not clear method?"

Comment: Look also here: https://pymotw.com/2/threading/#signaling-between-threads

Answer (score 4):

> Is there any use case where one would use set but not clear method?

Yes, if you want to block threads until a resource is available, this is one way to do it without polling. This resource could be a server, driver, or sensor that is not ready when starting up.

Another case to think about is how to pause threads when they aren't needed. Let's use a battery operated security camera as an example. The camera is activated by a motion sensor. The video and audio are expensive in terms of battery consumption. The motion sensor sets the event until a timer expires and no new motion has been detected. Once that expires, the event is cleared. This tells the video and audio threads to stop recording.

> I come from Java world and I couldn't help but to compare this with
>   wait and notify method calls.

The java wait, notify, and notifyAll methods match the behavior of python's Threading Condition. When a notify or notifyAll signals threads, one waiting thread gains control of a lock at a time. The other waiting threads must wait until that thread releases that lock before it can run.

Answer (score 1):

I'd say Python's `Event`s vs Java's `wait`/`notify` are implementing different abstractions and hence they're useful in different situations.

maybe you are looking for Python's [`Condition`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#condition-objects) class? this looks much closer to the Java `Object`'s `wait` and `notify` mechanisms, and even follows the same method naming convention

as a motivating example, think about the implementation of a [`Future`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Futures_and_promises) in Python, it could just `wait` on an `Event` knowing that it was only `set` when the  async code completed.  in Java you'd have to do something else because there's a race condition in code that does:

```java
synchronized (obj) {
  if (!obj.has_result) {
    obj.wait();
  }
  return obj.result;
}
```

Comment: I accept that Java's wait/notify is different from Python's Event. But in Event Objects why do we need a clear method explicitly? Can there be an instance where one would use set and not use clear. I cannot think of any.

Comment: @pvpkiran have added an example, but not sure if it's helpful.  maybe you could add a pointer to the sort of code that is easy with the abstraction that Java provides and why it's more difficult in Python

Comment: thanks for the code snippet(+1). Unfortunately it doesn't really help. I am not trying to compare if this is simpler in javaor python. My whole point is that the implementation of set method could have included clear as well, instead of user explicitly calling it(since clear is always used with set)

Comment: but if this is the abstraction you want why aren't you using a `Condition` rather than an `Event`?

Answer (score 1):

Quoted from Python Cookbook

> Event objects are best used for one-time events. That is, you create an event, threads
> wait for the event to be set, and once set, the Event is discarded. Although it is possible
> to clear an event using its clear() method, safely clearing an event and waiting for it
> to be set again is tricky to coordinate, and can lead to missed events, deadlock, or other
> problems

One scenario I could think of is you can reset the internal flag to `False` thus to make a period timer by using `.clear()`:

```
import threading
import time

e = threading.Event()

# task running on separate thread
def periodic_task():
    while True:
        e.wait()
        # do some stuff
        print('task completed!')
        e.clear()  # --> `.clear()` works like `.reset()`

t = threading.Thread(target=periodic_task)
t.start()

# main thread
while True:
    time.sleep(5)
    e.set()
```